# Using Add-Content with a ForEach

Tags: powershell

I am looking to run a Powershell script that will create another .ps1 that will set the Service startup type back to what it was originally. ie. SQL Server agent was set to Automatic, so set it back to Automatic. Since I need to do this for remote servers, this makes it a little more complicated. Here is my feeble start:

```
$SQLServices = Get-Service -ComputerName 'enter servername here' | Select-Object Name,DisplayName,Status,StartType | ?{$_.Displayname -match “SQL Server Agent” -AND $_.Status -eq "Running"}

ForEach {Add-Content -path 'c:\temp\RestartSQLServices.ps1' -value "Get-Service -ComputerName 'enter servername here' | Set-Service -Name $($_.Name) -StartupType $($_.StartType)"}
```

The new ps1 should read:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName 'enter servername here' | Set-Service -Name SQLSERVERAGENT -StartupType Automatic
```

But I can't seem to get the Service Name and StartType to be read from $SQLServices.

Thoughts???

Comment: as written, your code won't work because you aren't piping anything into the `foreach` cmdlet. So instead you are using the `foreach` keyword and your code will throw an error. Should there be a pipe character at the end of the first line?

Comment: I was getting an error regarding Add-Content and piping not allowed. I also tried adding ForEach ($svc in $SQLServices) {Add-Content .... but it made no difference.

Comment: This was the error:
The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to create another script?

Just check the service and reset it and are you sure you are using the correct service name.

```
Get-Service -ComputerName 'LabSQL01' -Name '*SQL*'

# Results

Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Running  MSSQLFDLauncher    SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launche...
Running  MSSQLSERVER        SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)              
Running  SQLBrowser         SQL Server Browser                    
Running  SQLSERVERAGENT     SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)        
Running  SQLTELEMETRY       SQL Server CEIP service (MSSQLSERVER) 
Running  SQLWriter          SQL Server VSS Writer 


($SQLServiceStatus = Get-Service -ComputerName 'LabSQL01' -Name 'SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)')

$SQLServiceStatus.StartType
Automatic

$SQLServiceStatus.Status
Running     

{Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'LabSQO01' -ScriptBlock {$SQLServiceStatus = Get-Service -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Name 'SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)'

If ($SQLServiceStatus.Status -eq 'Running')
{Set-Service -Name $($SQLServiceStatus.Name) -StartupType Automatic -WhatIf}
Else{ Write-Warning -Message "$($SQLServiceStatus.Name) is already set to the current state" }}
```

***Update for OP ***

OK, then, I am not real sure why the forloop for a single computer, unless you have multiple servers you plan to target, but, for a single target, how about.

```
New-Item -Path  "\\$LabSQL01\c$\temp" -Name 'RestartSQLServices.ps1' -ItemType File

# Results

    Directory: \\LabSQL01\c$\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        11/10/2018   3:39 PM          0 RestartSQLServices.ps1


Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$LabSQL01\c$\temp\RestartSQLServices.ps1"

# Results

    Directory: \\LabSQL01\c$\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        11/10/2018   3:39 PM          0 RestartSQLServices.ps1


$ScriptContents = @'
$SQLServiceStatus = Get-Service -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Name 'SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)'

If ($SQLServiceStatus.Status -eq 'Running')
{Set-Service -Name $($SQLServiceStatus.Name) -StartupType Automatic -WhatIf}
Else{ Write-Warning -Message "$($SQLServiceStatus.Name) is already set to the current state" }
'@

Add-Content -Path "\\$LabSQL01\c$\temp\RestartSQLServices.ps1" -Value $ScriptContents


Get-Content -Path "\\$LabSQL01\c$\temp\RestartSQLServices.ps1"

# Results

$SQLServiceStatus = Get-Service -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Name 'SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)'

If ($SQLServiceStatus.Status -eq 'Running')
{Set-Service -Name $($SQLServiceStatus.Name) -StartupType Automatic -WhatIf}
Else{ Write-Warning -Message "$($SQLServiceStatus.Name) is already set to the current state" }


Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$LabSQL01\c$\temp\RestartSQLServices.ps1"

# Results

    Directory: \\LabSQL01\c$\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        11/10/2018   3:45 PM        273 RestartSQLServices.ps1
```

Of course the can be easily tweaked for multiple targets.

Comment: The plan is to run a maintenance on all our SQL servers. During this maintenance, I will need to stop each SQL service and set it to Manual. This script would allow me to reset each StartType back to what it was set at originally.